# Gutenberg media upload in Inspect Controls

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to upload the file via Media Library from Inspect Control in Gutenberg. I am using this code currently in JS :

```
var el = wp.element.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    ServerSideRender = wp.components.ServerSideRender,
    TextControl = wp.components.TextControl,
    TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl,
    MediaUpload = wp.components.MediaUpload,
    InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
```

And here I am registering the block type :

```
    registerBlockType( 'myplugin/about-section', {
        title: 'About Section',
        icon: 'megaphone',
        category: 'widgets',
        edit: function( props ) {
            return [
                el( ServerSideRender, {
                    block: 'malinda/about-section',
                    attributes: props.attributes,
                } ),

                el( InspectorControls, {},
                    el( MediaUpload, {
                        label: 'Background Image',
                        value: props.attributes.bgimg,
// I think something need to be done here..
                    } ),
                ),
            ];
        },
        save: function() {
            return null;
        },
    } );
```

But for some reason it's not working for me. In console it's giving me this error :

> Error: Minified React error #130; visit
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=
>   for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full
>   errors and additional helpful warnings.

and when I click on block it says :

> The editor has encountered an unexpected error.

Can anyone please help me in that?

Comment: You can look in this article https://organicthemes.com/create-custom-block-wordpress-gutenberg/ and use code from https://github.com/Invulu/organic-profile-block/blob/master/block/profile/block.js

Comment: If you enable `SCRIPT_DEBUG` in your `wp-config.php` by adding the line `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );`, you will see unminified react errors that will give you more information and help in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need add attributes field for save image link. Then you need add MediaUpload element and add callback on click. And after save value. You can integrate my code in your 
decision. I am add image select to inspector controls area.

```js
    ( function( editor, components, i18n, element ) {
    
     var el = element.createElement;
     var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
     var InspectorControls = wp.editor.InspectorControls;
        var MediaUpload = wp.editor.MediaUpload;
    
     registerBlockType( 'designa/image-block', {
      title: 'Image block',
      description: 'Image block.',
      icon: 'video-alt3',
      category: 'common',
      
      attributes: {
       mediaURL: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'attribute',
        selector: 'img',
        attribute: 'src',
       }
      },
    
    
      edit: function( props ) {
          
          var attributes = props.attributes;
          
          var onSelectImage = function( media ) {
        return props.setAttributes({
         mediaURL: media.url
        });
       };
    
       return [
                    
        el( InspectorControls, { key: 'inspector' },
         el( components.PanelBody, {
          title: 'Image block',
          className: 'image-block',
          initialOpen: true,
         },
    
          el( MediaUpload, {
           onSelect: onSelectImage,
           type: 'image',
           render: function( obj ) {
            return el( components.Button, {
                 className: 'components-icon-button image-block-btn is-button is-default is-large',
                 onClick: obj.open
             },
             el( 'svg', { className: 'dashicon dashicons-edit', width: '20', height: '20' },
              el( 'path', { d: "M2.25 1h15.5c.69 0 1.25.56 1.25 1.25v15.5c0 .69-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25H2.25C1.56 19 1 18.44 1 17.75V2.25C1 1.56 1.56 1 2.25 1zM17 17V3H3v14h14zM10 6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2s-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2zm3 5s0-6 3-6v10c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H5c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V8c2 0 3 4 3 4s1-3 3-3 3 2 3 2z" } )
             ),
             el( 'span', {},
                 'Select image'
             ),
            );
           }
          }),
         
         ),
        )
                    
       ];
      },
    
    
      save: function( props ) {
       var attributes = props.attributes;
    
       return (
           el( 'div', {
         className: props.className
        },
            el( 'img', {
                src: attributes.mediaURL
            })
        )
       );
    
      },
    
    
     } );
    
    } )(
     window.wp.editor,
     window.wp.components,
     window.wp.i18n,
     window.wp.element,
    );
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible to resize the image for the save function, so it's web optimized?

Comment: On select callback you have "media" object, you can get image size or image thumbnail size or your custom size, simple use console.log(media); to see what you can use. And after you can set image thumbnail size or add custom image width with style attribute or add input field to add style attribute.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!